# Android - Can't open chrome with specified local file but can access file when chrome is open

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-intent

I use this code to open a browser with a specified local file

```
        String url = "file:///storage/sdcard0/Files/AppFolder/main.html";
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);  

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        intent.setPackage("com.android.chrome");

        try {
            context.startActivity(intent);
        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException ex) 
            intent.setPackage(null);
            wrapper.startActivity(intent);
        }
```

This does not work; I get an error "The document cannot be opened because it is not a valid PDF document". For some reason, adobe reader tries to open the file instead of chrome.

If I use "http://www.facebook.com", chrome will open Facebook, and then I can put "file:///storage/sdcard0/Files/AppFolder/main.html" and it will open my main.html file.

Can anyone tell me why I cannot get chrome to open with my local url specified?

Comment: Did you check, that your hardcoded path is correct?

Comment: yes the path is correct, I can open the file using that path when the browser is already open (i.e. I type in that path into the broswers text field)